# How to get comma separated values from a table linked with foriegn key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue where i want to return a list of images in the response.
I created an foreign key named pest_id which is linked to the main KnowledgeBase Table. Now if i use the specified way, like

```
KnowledgeBase.objects.values('id', 'pest_id', 'pest__name', 
'pest__title', 'pestimages__image', 'front_image', 'cause', 
'effect', 'remedy', 'prevention')
```

I get the list, but the output is

```
{
        "id": 1473,
        "pest_id": 249,
        "pest__name": "Worker stuff little store three operation news. Move world affect small. Entire past face partner.",
        "pest__title": "surya",
        "pestimages__image": "extras/f4e8482c69e4e562d86149b45da8565e.jpg",
        "front_image": "images/plant-3250.jpg",
        "cause": "Summer popular music provide white.",
        "effect": "That unit article practice feel nature.",
        "remedy": "Car including hair before impact least scene tough. Generation job painting in develop issue mean half.",
        "prevention": "Every business price step themselves own. Treatment guess far senior response. See a development last."
    },
    {
        "id": 1473,
        "pest_id": 249,
        "pest__name": "Worker stuff little store three operation news. Move world affect small. Entire past face partner.",
        "pest__title": "surya",
        "pestimages__image": "extras/f2f05d15bf695d5bb45ca909887230f9.jpg",
        "front_image": "images/plant-3250.jpg",
        "cause": "Summer popular music provide white.",
        "effect": "That unit article practice feel nature.",
        "remedy": "Car including hair before impact least scene tough. Generation job painting in develop issue mean half.",
        "prevention": "Every business price step themselves own. Treatment guess far senior response. See a development last."
    },
```

But the expected output is:

```
{
        "pest_id": 249,
        "id": 1473,
        "pest__name": "Worker stuff little store three operation news. Move world affect small. Entire past face partner.",
        "pest__title": "surya",
        "images": [
            "extras/f4e8482c69e4e562d86149b45da8565e.jpg",
            "extras/f2f05d15bf695d5bb45ca909887230f9.jpg",
            "extras/ea1a1b02e734d1130c80e45880c106d3.jpg",
            "extras/e66b165e767d45ac2ef046873a27ed29.jpg",
            "extras/e54ed50db3e1079db9284bd30494de76.jpg",
            "extras/de37d314715709b183d88ec82184330a.jpg",
            "extras/dac29948d89054e2ede1b957b53d3ec6.jpg",
            "extras/d7750c85b3e5d0b3cb7adaffa5474a11.jpg",
            "extras/d468a3e96a0a7249a32e614ab7a4d8fa.jpg"
        ],
        "front_image": "images/plant-3250.jpg",
        "cause": "Summer popular music provide white.",
        "effect": "That unit article practice feel nature.",
        "remedy": "Car including hair before impact least scene tough. Generation job painting in develop issue mean half.",
        "prevention": "Every business price step themselves own. Treatment guess far senior response. See a development last."
    },
```

So, you can see that the whole result is being repeated as many times as the the PestImages table has the foreign key pest_id.

What i actually wanted was that it should return the pestimages__image field in Comma separated values.

Do i need to change my models?

I've tried searching for solutions regrading my issue but was unable to find any hint for this.

Ultimately i had to write my own method, which is taking a lot of time to process the results.

```
id_list = KnowledgeBase.objects.values_list('id')
    ResponseList = []
    for id in range(len(id_list)):
        kb = KnowledgeBase.objects.get(id=id_list[id][0])
        pests = Pest.objects.get(id=kb.pest_id)
        pestimg = [', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in PestImages.objects.filter(pest_id=id_list[id][0]).values_list('image')]
        ResponseList.append(
            {
                 'pest_id': kb.pest_id,
                 'id': id_list[id][0],
                 'pest__name': pests.name,
                 'pest__title': pests.title,
                 'images': pestimg,
                 'front_image': str(kb.front_image),
                 'cause': kb.cause,
                 'effect': kb.effect,
                 'remedy': kb.remedy,
                 'prevention': kb.prevention
            }
        )
    return Response(ResponseList, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now, although this function serves my purpose, but it takes 1700ms to respond when compared to 26ms of the normal method.

My Models are:

```
class KnowledgeBase(models.Model):
    pest = models.OneToOneField(Pest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cause = models.TextField()
    front_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=False, null=False, default='images/plant-3250.jpg')
    effect = models.TextField()
    remedy = models.TextField()
    prevention = models.TextField()

class PestImages(models.Model):
    pest = models.ForeignKey('KnowledgeBase', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='extras')

class Pest(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

The time difference is huge:

> ~30ms with normal function with redundant info
>   Normal Function : KnowledgeBase.objects.values(*)

[image: <30ms with normal function with redundant info]

> ~1700ms with my function/using serialization..
>
> My function is posted above and the serialization method is listed in the answer.

[image: >1700ms with my function/using serialization]

Comment: Please comment if anyone wants more information, i'll add the points in the question.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'll add them in the question.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @JPG you deleted your answer? Serializing is the way forward for me. I'll check onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class KnowledgeBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    pest__name = serializer.Charfield(source="pest.name")
    pest__title = serializer.Charfield(source="pest.title")

    def get_images(self, kb):
        return [str(item) for item in kb.pestimages__image.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = KnowledgeBase
        fields = ('id', 'pest_id', 'pest__name', 'pest__title', 'front_image', 'cause', 'effect', 'remedy', 'prevention', 'images')
```

and then,

```
mydata = KnowledgeBaseSerializer(KnowledgeBase.objects.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `pest__name` is not valid for model `KnowledgeBase`.
This is the error being raised

Comment: After correcting the two lines,
    
    pest__name = serializers.CharField(source="pest.name")
    pest__title = serializers.CharField(source="pest.title")

I'm getting,
AttributeError: 'KnowledgeBase' object has no attribute 'pestimages__image'

Comment: And using serializer isn't reducing the time. Please check the uploaded images in the question.

Comment: Why my edit was rejected? There's a syntax error in the answer.